# REGEXP_INSTR equivalence in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to find an equivalence for `REGEXP_INSTR` (Oracle) to find the nth occurrence of a pattern. Currently `Patindex` finds only the first occurrence.  I need to find to second occurrence of  pattern '%[*-/]$' in string '11111-2222-3333-44' or '11111*2222*3333*44' or '11111/2222/3333/44'.

Final result will be: 1111-3333-44

```
declare @itemcode varchar(50)  ='11111-2222-3333-44'  
declare @regex varchar(10)='%[/*-]%'  
select   
CASE  
      WHEN PATINDEX(@regex,@itemcode)<=0 THEN NULL  
      ELSE   CASE  
             WHEN   PATINDEX(@regex,SUBSTRING(@itemcode,PATINDEX(@regex,@itemcode)+1,100))<=0 THEN NULL  
             ELSE   SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@itemcode,PATINDEX(@regex,@itemcode)+1,100),PATINDEX(@regex,SUBSTRING(@itemcode,PATINDEX(@regex,@itemcode)+1,100))+1,100)  
           END  
    END
```

Comment: You seem to have already found the answer, which is `patindex` in a substring based on the first `patindex`.

Comment: I'm looking for a table/scalar function  to handle many occurences. Mine is only good for second occurence and begin hard to read even at two occurences.

Comment: Sometimes, it's easiest to delegate this to a CLR function if writing this in T-SQL is too cumbersome. E.g. see [Common Language Runtime Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/common-language-runtime-integration-overview) and [CLR User-Defined Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-user-defined-functions).